# How do I make it so a button can only be clicked if a condition is met that is set in another class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, button

In the `ShowMoneyButton` class, I want the `activation` function to only activate if `self.button_activated` is False, and I set it as False when the `SongButton` class's `activation` function is triggered, yet it's not registering. It stays True. Is there a way I can make it so the `ShowMoneyButton` class's activation function is executed only if the `SongButton` class's `activation` function is executed, except for the first time?

```
import tkinter as tk, random, subprocess, time, os, datetime, pprint


class Song:

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = []
        self.path = "/users/eliasrahoui/desktop/songy"
        for filename in os.listdir(self.path):
            self.files.append(self.path + "/" + filename)

class Money_Value:

    def __init__(self):
        with open("money_counter.txt", "r") as f:
            a = f.read()
        a = int(a)
        self.current_value = a

class Clock:

    def __init__(self, root):
        money = Money_Value()
        self.money = money.current_value
        self.root = root
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "$" + str(self.money), foreground = "green", font = ('calibri', 100, 'bold'))
        self.label.pack()

    def countup(self, *args):
        root = self.root
        money_per_hour = 1000
        self.money += 1
        self.label['text'] = "$" + str(self.money)
        self.root_id = root.after(money_per_hour, self.countup)

    def stop(self):
        root = self.root
        root.after_cancel(self.root_id)
        with open("money_counter.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(self.money))
    def save(self):
        with open("money_counter.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(self.money))
        self.root.destroy()

class Button:

    all_buttons = {}
    windows = []
    return_code = []
    button_activated = False
    def __init__(self, root, text, command):
        self.text = text
        button = tk.Button(root, text = text, command = command)
        self.all_buttons[self.text] = button

    def remove(self, button):
        button.pack_forget()

    def show_button(self, button):
        button.pack(side ="bottom")

class SongButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, root, clock):
        self.root = root
        self.root_clock = clock
        super().__init__(self.root, text = "stop song", command = self.activation)

    def activation(self): 
        windows = self.windows
        for i in windows:
            i.destroy()
        code = self.return_code[-1]
        code.kill()
        self.remove(self.all_buttons["stop song"])
        self.root_clock.countup()
        self.button_activated = False
        

class ShowMoneyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, root, clock):
        self.root = root
        super().__init__(self.root, "show me the money", self.activation)
        song = Song()
        self.songs = song.files
        money_show_button = self.all_buttons["show me the money"]
        self.show_button(money_show_button) 
        self.pic = tk.PhotoImage(file = "/users/eliasrahoui/desktop/IMG_7465.png")
        #self.button_activated = False
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "")
        self.root_clock = clock

    def activation(self):
        if self.button_activated == False:
            self.root_clock.stop()
            num = Money_Value()
            money = num.current_value
            self.label.config(text =f'Money {money}')
            self.label.pack()
            random_song = random.choice(self.songs)
            a = SongButton(self.root, self.root_clock)
            return_cod = subprocess.Popen(["afplay", random_song])
            self.return_code.append(return_cod)
            self.show_button(self.all_buttons["stop song"])
            self.button_activated = True
            for _ in range(30):
                root = self.root
                window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
                self.windows.append(window)
                window.minsize(100, 100)
                window_label = tk.Label(window, image = self.pic)
                window_label.pack()
                ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
                hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
                x = random.randint(0, ws)
                y = random.randint(0, hs)
                w = 200
                h = 200
                window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

class Timer(Button):

    def __init__(self, root, start_time, name, counter = False):
        self.count_down_start_time = start_time
        self.root = root
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.tmp_counter = counter
        super().__init__(self.root, text = name, command = self.timer_window)
        self.show_button(self.all_buttons[self.name])
        self.timer_id = None
        self.window_label = None
        self.orignial = start_time
        self.window = None
        self.current_question = 1
        self.questions_answered = {}
        self.times = [self.orignial]
        self.positive = False
        self.min_max = {}

    def timer_window(self):
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 200, 500, 300))
        self.window_label = tk.Label(self.window, text = "", font = ('calibri', 100, 'bold'))
        self.counter_label = tk.Label(self.window, text = f'Current Question: {self.current_question}')
        self.window_label.pack()
        self.timer()

    def timer(self):
        mins, secs = divmod(self.count_down_start_time, 60)
        mins = abs(mins)
        secs = abs(secs)
        timerr = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)  
        if self.count_down_start_time == -1:
            self.positive = True
            self.window_label["foreground"] = "red"
        if self.positive:
            self.count_down_start_time += 1
        else:    
            self.count_down_start_time -= 1
        self.window_label["text"] = timerr
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
        if self.counter == True:
            button = tk.Button(self.window, text = "Question Done!", command = self.counter_func)
            button.pack(side = "bottom")
            button_report =  tk.Button(self.window, text = "Report", command = self.report)
            self.counter = False
            self.counter_label.pack()
            button_report.pack(side = "bottom")
        self.timer_id = self.window.after(1000, self.timer)

    def callback(self):
        self.window.after_cancel(self.timer_id)
        self.window.destroy()
        self.count_down_start_time = self.orignial
        if self.tmp_counter == True:
            self.counter = True
            self.current_question = 1
        self.questions_answered = {}
        self.positive = False
        self.times = [self.orignial]

    def counter_func(self):
        self.questions_answered[self.current_question] = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = self.times[-1] - self.count_down_start_time))
        self.times.append(self.count_down_start_time)
        self.current_question += 1
        self.counter_label["text"] = f'Current Question: {self.current_question}'
        
        
    def report(self):
        vals = self.times_min_max()
        new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.window)
        new_window.minsize(300,300)
        a = self.questions_answered[1]
        data_pretty = pprint.pformat(self.questions_answered)
        label = tk.Label(new_window, text = data_pretty)
        label.pack()
        mx = {f'Maximum time took per question: {vals[0]} question numbers': vals[2]} 
        mn = {f'Minimum time took per question: {vals[1]} question numbers': vals[-1]}
        mx_label = tk.Label(new_window, text = mx, font =  ('calibri', 14, 'bold'))
        mn_label = tk.Label(new_window, text = mn, font = ('calibri', 14, 'bold'))
        mn_label.pack(side = "bottom")
        mx_label.pack(side = "bottom")
        
    def times_min_max(self):
        f = {}
        big = []
        small = []
        for i in range(1, len(self.questions_answered) + 1):
            val = self.questions_answered[i]
            if ":" in val:
                q = val.split(":")
                secs = int(q[-1])
                mins = q[0]
                secs = secs/60
                secs = str(secs)
                secs = secs.split(".")
                secs = secs[-1]
                final = mins + "." + secs
                final = (float(final)) * 60
                final = round(final)
                f[i] = final
            else:
                f[i] = int(val)
        max_val = max(f, key = f.get) #max(f.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        min_val = min(f, key=f.get)#min(f.keys(), key=(lambda key: f[key]))#min(f.items(), key = operator.intemgetter(1))[0]
        min_val = f[min_val]
        max_val = f[max_val]
        for i in f.keys():
            if f[i] == max_val:
                big.append(i)
            if f[i] == min_val:
                small.append(i)


        return (self.questions_answered[big[0]], self.questions_answered[small[0]], big, small)
```

main function:

```
import clocky_classy as cm
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(400,200)

my_clock = cm.Clock(root)
money_button = cm.ShowMoneyButton(root, my_clock)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", my_clock.save)

timer = cm.Timer(root, 120, "2 min timer")
timer = cm.Timer(root, 1800, "30 min timer", counter = True)

my_clock.countup()





root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the main function?

Comment: @JacksonPro I added it rn

Comment: What's inside your `money.txt` file?

Comment: an integer like 200

Comment: @JacksonPro ^, and the songy folder is a bunch of mp3 downloads